# Merge multiple instances of an object into one in Java

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class

```
class Dealer {
  String location;
  List<Car> cars;
}
```

I have 2 instances of this class

```
dealer1 = new Dealer("abc", ["Acura", "Honda"]);
dealer2 = new Dealer("xyz", ["BMW", "Audi"]);
```

There is a list containing both instances:

```
List<Dealer> dealers = [dealer1, dealer2];
```

Is there a Java Stream way to merge the list of dealers into a single dealer, independent of the location but combining the list of cars available for all dealers ?

Final resultant object:

```
Dealer(["Acura", "Honda", "BMW", "Audi"])
```

Comment: Why do you want a "dealer" instead of simply a combined list?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. But it's not going to be particularly pretty because it's a bit odd. Break dealers down into cars, flatmap your 'stream of streams' into just a stream (that's what flatmap does; lets you map an object into a stream and then 'unpack' all streams into a single stream), and then collect back to list, and use that to make a new dealer.

```
List<Car> allCars = dealers.stream()
  .map(Dealer::getCars)
  .flatMap(List::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
return new Dealer("Whatever location you want", allCars);
```

Comment: Maybe, a `distinct` wouldn't hurt

Comment: Or `.collect(collectingAndThen(toList(), cars -> new Dealer("location", cars)))`